# Conky dual screen positioning

Tags: multiple-monitors, conky, 17.10

I'm using Conky on Ubuntu 17.10 to display system informations on my desktop.

My computer has 2 monitors and I would like to move Conky to the 2nd one that is on the right, but I haven't found any informations on how I can perform that.

Here is a screen of my desktop:

[image]

Any help would be most welcome!

Comment: Hold down the alt key. Right click on the Conky window and drag it anywhere. Or maybe its left click--I'm on my phone. Bonus; if you put a desktop shortcut on your right monitor to open Conky it activates there in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually possible to drag the Conky Window ? I tried alt + right or left click while Conky Manager is open and it doesn't move.

Comment: It could be I use a different window type than you. I'll have to check it when I get home and get back to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally managed to move the Conky widget to the second monitor using negative values for the horizontal gap (-1920) after choosing `Bottom Right` in Conky Manager.
And now my desktop looks like this:

[image: Ubuntu desktop with Conky on a different monitor than the principal one]

If anyone has a better solution I would consider choosing it as the accepted answer.

Comment: may i ask how you setup the different background for each screen?

Comment: @ReubenTilahun that was actually a dual screen background!

Answer (score 27):

use `xinerama_head` config as suggested in [this issue discussion](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/issues/249)

```
xinerama_head = 2,
```

try with different number 1, 2

You might also want to use `alignment` so that conky widget appears not cropped by screen border

```
alignment = {top|middle|bottom}_right
```

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely disable conky's alignment by setting `alignment = none` and put absolute `gap_x` and `gap_y` values. This will allow widget positioning at any place without weird negative shifting.

As an example: 
to put a 200px wide widget in the right top corner of the right monitor, calculation will be simple:

```
gap_x = <left_monitor_width> + <right_monitor_width> - <widget_width>
```

In my case:

```
gap_x = 1680 + 1680 - 200 = 3160
```

and the config will look next:

```
conky.config = {
    ...
    alignment = none,
    gap_x = 3160,
    gap_y = 0,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After editing and saving the Conky config file, it worked on my main screen on a dual-screen setting.

This is what I used on a 1920*1080(16:9) screen.

```
alignment = 'top_right',
gap_x = 0,
gap_y = 33,
```